# Android: From StringArray Resources To CharSequence[]

Tags: android, resources, charsequence

I guess this is a pretty newbie question, but I've spent only 2 weeks on Android.

My question is, I have a StringArray created with a reference R.array.NAME

I want to populate a Dialog full of checkboxes with the values from the StringArray, but it seems I need to convert it to CharSequence[] so I can use:
setMultiChoiceItems

I can't find a way to do it.

This is my code (I have to add accept/cancel buttons anyway)

// I want this (subjects variable) to be gotten from my `StringArray R.array.NAME`

```
final CharSequence[] subjects = {"Sports", "History", "Maths"};         
final boolean[] states = {false, true, false};    
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(subjects, states, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item, boolean state) {
            }
        });
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From within your Activity call:

```
String[] subjects = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.NAME);
```

To obtain the value of the resource.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But I need a CharSequence. I tried that and it doesn't work with the parameter of builder.setMultiChoiceItems

Comment: A String[] is a CharSequence[] and yes, it can be passed to AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: @Sento you'll have to tell us what "doesn't work" means. A String[] can be used anywhere a CharSequence[] can.

Comment: Ok man, I'm very sorry. I was still using getIntArray instead of getStringArray. Now it's all working. I apologize :_

Answer (score 0):

```
CharSequence[] subjects =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subjectsName);
```